# Why can I cancel in modular arithmetic when working modulus a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Working modulus a prime number in modular arithmetic let's you cancel factors in a congruence equation. Let p and k be integers, p a prime number and k not a multiple of p:

$a \cdot k\equiv b \cdot k\pmod n$

We can multiply by a constant on each side and maintain the congruence. Let this constant be a multiplicative inverse of k (which is guaranteed to exist in this case).

$a \cdot k \cdot k^{-1}\equiv b \cdot k \cdot k^{-1}\pmod n$

Why is it that I can now justify canceling the initial k? $k \cdot k^{-1}$ gives some integer $m$, which when divided by $n$ gives remainder 1. But what is the property that takes me from $a \cdot m\equiv b \cdot m\pmod n$ to $a\equiv b\pmod n$?

Comment: you know what is a group ? and that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},\times)$ is a   group ? and that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ is a field ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an entirely elementary approach.

Instead of writing $k^{-1}$, write $x$ for any of the integers such that $k x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so that $k x = 1 + p t$ for some $t$.

Therefore
$$
a k x = a (1 + p t) = a + a p t \equiv a \pmod{p}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For any positive integer $n$, the members of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ that are coprime to $n$ form a group.  In particular, they have multiplicative inverses mod $n$.  If $a m \equiv b m \mod n$ and $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then $a \equiv b \mod n$.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, and did some research. There is a theorem which states if $ca\equiv cb\mod m$, then $a \equiv b \mod \frac{m}{\gcd(c,m)}$. It can be found on page 229 of [The Nature and Power of Mathematics by Donald M. Davis](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Nature_and_Power_of_Mathematics.html?id=qn7rYiyS7mUC). So in your example, you can cancel out $k$ because $n$ is prime and $k$ is not a multiple of $n$, so $\gcd(k,n)=1$.