# Show this code has a minimun distance of $d=2$

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

The code words of C are in the form :

$a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7$

Where $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6$ are any numbers in the arithmetic field:  $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

And:

$a_7=-\left( 7a_{1}+6a_{2}+5a_{3}+4a_{4}+3a_{5}+2a_{6}\right)$

**Show that the code has minimum distance $d=2$**

How would we do this ?

On a side note, I reading through the solution apparently $a_{7}=0$. Was just wondering how this was so ? Is it because $a_{7}$ it is not apart of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Comment: I guess that all $a_i$ are in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ (it would make little sense otherwise), and the operation for $a_7$ is understood to be in $\pmod{ 11}$ Do we agree here?

Answer (score 2):

The parity equation is 
$$ 7a_{1}+6a_{2}+5a_{3}+4a_{4}+3a_{5}+2a_{6} + a_7 = \sum_{i=1}^7 (8-i)a_i= 0 \pmod{11} \tag{1}$$

Question: can there be two tuples ${\bf b}$, ${\bf c}$ that verify $(1)$ and which differ only in one position? Answer: no. If this were true, suppose in position  $i\in \{1,2 \cdots 7\}$ ($b_i\ne c_i$); then, susbtracting both parity equations we'd obtain

$$(8-i)b_i = (8-i)c_i \pmod{11} \tag{2}$$
But, because $11$ is prime, we 
can [cancel the factor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754546/why-can-i-cancel-in-modular-arithmetic-when-working-modulus-a-prime-number), then we'd get $b_i=c_i$ - contradiction.

Then two different tuples ${\bf b}$, ${\bf c}$ must differ in at least 2 positions, hence $d_{\min} \ge 2$. That this bound is attained is easy to see. Take for example two tuples that coincide in the first 5 positions and differ in $a_6$ (they are part of the code because it includes all six-length tuples). Hence  $d_{\min} = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

The [parity check matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix) of the code is
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}
7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since all the columns are different from zero, but any pair is linearly dependent, the minimum distance is $2$.

In fact, quoting from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix),

> the minimum distance of a code is the minimum number $d$ such that every $d - 1$ columns of a parity-check matrix $H$ are linearly independent while there exist $d$ columns of $H$ that are linearly dependent.