# Why can I cancel in modular arithmetic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Based on my school, the cancellation law for modular arithmetic is as stated:

> For all integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $n$, with $n > 1$ and $a$ and $n$ are coprime, if $ab$
>   $≡ ac $( $mod$ $n$), then $b ≡ c$ ( $mod$ $n$ ).

Apparently, the proof for this was to multiply both sides by $a$<sup>-1</sup>.

---

2 questions then stem from this:

1) If you do modular multiplication, shouldn't you multiply the modulus as well?

If $a \equiv b \mod n$, then $ma\equiv mb \mod {nm}$. Why isn't this happening when $a$<sup>-1</sup> is multiplied on both sides,i.e. I don't see a $a$<sup>-1</sup> in the modulus?

---

2)Isn't multiplicative inverse of modulo $n$ such that $a$<sup>-1</sup>$a$ ≡ $1$ ( $mod$ $n$) (ie must be congruent to *1 modulo n*)?

> $\boxed{\text{Solve the equation $5 x+13 y=75$ for integers $x, y\quad$  }}$
>
> Such an equation is called a $\color{red}{\text{Diophantine equation}}$.
>
> 1. Re-write: $5 x=75-13 y$
> 2. Then $5 x \equiv 75(\bmod 13),$ by Theorem $8.4 .1$ (Epp)
> 3. Re-write: $5 x \equiv 5 \cdot 15(\bmod 13)$
> 4. Note that 5 and 13 are coprime.
> 5. Thus, $x \equiv 15(\bmod 13),$ by Theorem $8.4 .9$ (Epp)
> 6. Thus, $x \equiv 2(\bmod 13),$ because 15 mod $13=2$
> 7. So $x=2$ is a solution.
> 8. Substituting back into the equation: $5(2)+13 y=75$
> 9. And thus $y=5$

[(Transcribed from this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6u8K.png)

As you can see, on line 5, when they multiply both sides by $5$<sup>-1</sup>, its not congruent to *1 modulo 13*?

---

PS:

I looked up on this possible duplicate: [Why can I cancel in modular arithmetic when working modulus a prime number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1754546/789305) but didn't seem to understand both the poster and the answerer.

Comment: In $b\equiv c\mod n$ ... , it should be $b\equiv c\mod m$. In this case, it is not difficult to show the implication. The other direction is more difficult.

Comment: there are a number of answers in the duplicate. Can you point to where you dont understand in the elementary one?

Comment: @CalvinKhor If possible, I would like to understand the 1st answer

Comment: @Peter are you referring to the blockquote?

Comment: No, to this : If b≡c ( mod n ), then na≡nb (mod nm). Why isn't this happening when a-1 is multiplied on both sides,ie I don't see a a-1 in the modulus?

Comment: Additionally, why $c$ and then $a$ ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\equiv b \mod n$, then we can write $a=b+kn$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So multiplying by $m$ say gives $am=bm+knm$, which can be written as $am\equiv bm \mod mn$, but also as $am\equiv bm \mod n$, with $km$ as the 'new' $k$.

$a^{-1}$ exists as $\gcd(a,n)=1$, and is an integer between  $1$ and $n-1$, and doesn't appear in the modulus for the reason given above.

For part 2, $5^{-1}\cdot 5\equiv 1 \mod {13}$, and

$$5x\equiv 5\cdot15 \mod {13}$$
$$ 5^{-1}\cdot 5x\equiv 5^{-1}\cdot 5\cdot15 \mod {13} $$
$$ x\equiv 15 \mod {13}$$

Comment: For part 2) , are you saying that, multiplying by its inverse does guarantee a congruency to *1 modulo n*. Its just the $x$ causing my confusion that makes it a congruency to *2 modulo n* instead?

Comment: @Leon; the inverse is multiplied on line 3, and only affects the $5$ and not $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying both sides of a modular equation without changing the modulus is valid, and if two numbers are equivalent modulo $pq$, they're certainly equivalent modulo $p$. (It's division that's a little more iffy.)

In this case, multiplying by $a^{-1}$ isn't necessary (although it does work, with some justification). A better way to do this is to observe that
$$ab \equiv ac \pmod n$$
implies
$$a(b-c) = ab - ac \equiv 0 \pmod n,$$
which means that $n|a(b-c)$. Since $n$ and $a$ are coprime, this then means $n|b-c$, or in other words, $b \equiv c \pmod n$.

For your second question, $a a^{-1}$ being $1$ modulo $n$ doesn't mean that multiplying anything with an $a^{-1}$ yields $1$ mod $n$. The inverse of $5$ is $8$; you can check easily that $5 \times 8 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$, and that multiplying $8$ on both sides in line 3 yields line 5.

Comment: The alternative explanation was nice!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In a commutative ring $R$,  $ab=ac$ implies $b=c$ if $a\ne0$ is not a zero divisor. It’s not necessary that $a$ is a unit.

Indeed, if $ab=ac$, then $a(b-c)=0$. Since $a$ is not a zero divisor, then $b-c=0$ and hence $b=c$.

In the ring $Z_n$, each nonzero element is a zero divisor or a unit. So this is a special case.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learnt  this topic "rings"

Comment: Just think about $Z_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $ab=ac$ mod $n$ iff there is some integer $k$ such that $a(b-c)=kn$. In particular $a $ is a divisor of the product $kn$. Now you use the coprime assumption: none of the prime factors of $a$ divide $n$, so all of them must divide $k$; so $a$ divides $k$, which is to say $k/a=j$ is some integer $j\in\mathbb Z$. Thus
$$b-c = (k/a) n = jn $$
so $b=c$ mod $n$.